# How to remove roles from a user in every server? Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a verification bot and I want to do a command where if somebody unlinks their Roblox account then it removes the verified role from them in all the servers they are in. I know how to do it in a single server like this:

```
role1 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Verified')
await ctx.author.remove_roles(role1)
```

But how would I do it across all of the servers the member is in with the bot. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A role is unique per guild, you'd need to iterate through every guild, get the member and role, and remove it.

```py
for guild in bot.guilds:
    member = guild.get_member(member_id) # Change the ID accordingly
  
    if member is not None:
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Verified')

        await member.remove_roles(role)
```

This code loops through every guild the bot is in, tried to get the member, if it's not a nonetype (cause the member doesn't have to share that specific guild with the bot), it gets the role obj and removes it.

Reference:

- [`Bot.guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20guilds#discord.ext.commands.Bot.guilds)
- [`Guild.get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20get_member#discord.Guild.get_member)

Also you need `intents.guilds` and `intents.members`